# How to scale along LOCAL xyz axis?

Tags: transforms

when the object has been rotated and I wanna scale the object along its local axis.
For example,

1. can I make the object in red thinner by scaling along its xy plane?
2. can I extend the object by scaling along its local z-axis?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Scale along local Z axis, press <kbd>S</kbd> to enter scale operator, then while scaling press <kbd>Z</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> for local Z axis

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.